# How does switching covers affect bodily needs?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, demon-the-descent

Demon's can have multiple covers, but they can't have multiple covers active at the same time. When a cover isn't active, it's my understanding that it basically doesn't exist. These bodies have the normal needs to eat and sleep, etc. Demon states that Demons aren't used to these needs. But what happens when you switch covers? Does the active cover have the same needs as the previous one?

Example: if I have covers A and B, and A is hungry and I switch to B, is B hungry? Or does A remain hungry the next time I switch to A (like a low battery I swapped out but still needs to charge)? Or perhaps neither is true, and when you switch back to A it is no longer hungry.

My biggest thought isn't really food but sleep: can a demon get away with not sleeping by switching to another cover?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I [cross posted to the Onyx Path forums](http://forum.theonyxpath.com/forum/main-category/main-forum/the-new-world-of-darkness/demon-the-descent/407680-how-does-switching-covers-affect-bodily-needs), and Rose Bailey, an Onyx Path employee, responded.

> Hunger and fatigue are constant across Covers.

Answer (score 4):

A demon's Demonic Form and all their Covers exist at the same time, on top of one another. It's described in terms of quantum superposition where an unobserved particle can be in multiple mutually-exclusive states simultaneously.

Switching between Covers doesn't cause hunger because the Cover isn't a separate body; it's just one state of the same body. This is also the reason why injuries carry over -- all states took the bullet -- and Covers age even when they're not in use. (*Demon: the Descent* p. 182 Age & Injury)

*Flowers of Hell* p. 24 says that "Hunger, thirst, fatigue, and so on fall away" when they enter the Demonic Form. So it might be possible for a demon to avoid eating or sleeping by switching to their Demonic Form, but that can present its own problems and risks.